# node js overriding toString

Tags: node.js

I am trying to override the default toString method for my objects, Here is the code and the problem:

```
function test (){
     this.code = 0;//later on I will set these
     this.name = "";
}

test.prototype.toString= function(){
    return this.name + "\t"+ this.code +" \t "+this.anotherFunction();
}

console.log (Lion.toString()); //works correct i.e. calls my function
console.log (Lion); //doesn't call my function. Prints { code: 0, name: 'jack' }
```

doesn't toString get called by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Came across this on google before finding an answer I liked, here is what I ended up doing:

You can use `inspect` and v8(chrome/nodejs) will use that from console.log() calls:

```js
function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.inspect = function() {
  return "[object Foo]";
}

console.log(new Foo());
```

Comment: does not seem to work in Chrome 94

Answer (score 6):

Not always. Browsers like Chrome allow you to inspect the object (for debugging purpose) via console.log().

Try this:

```
console.log (''+Lion);
```

Answer (score 5):

I was interested in how to do this too, once I saw how nicely [Immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) prints out objects:

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');
var map = Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b: 2 });
console.log(map); // Map { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

After some source code scanning, I discovered they pull it off by adding both [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and `inspect` methods to an object's prototype. Here's the basic idea, more or less:

```
function Map(obj) {
  this.obj = obj;
}
Map.prototype.toString = function () {
  return 'Map ' + JSON.stringify(this.obj);
}
Map.prototype.inspect = function () {
  return this.toString();
}
```

Having both `toString` and `inspect` methods means that the object will get logged out correctly in node (using `inspect`), and will be correctly formatted as a string if necessary (using `toString`).

EDIT: This only applies to node, browsers will still log out the object. If you don't want this, first convert it to a string either by calling `toString` or by concatenating it with another string: `console.log('' + map)`.

Answer (score 2):

No. Adding something to prototype makes it available, but doesn't mean it will be called simply because you create an instance of the object to which it belongs.

For example:

```
function foo() {
   var bar = 123;
}
foo.prototype.show_bar = function() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}

var x = new foo(); // does not log anything
x.show_bar(); // logs 123
```

I think your confusion is thinking that `console.log()` automatically tries to convert its parameter to a string. It doesn't; it can output arrays, objects, functions, etc.

Comment: I see, I was thinking when I console.log an object it always calls the toString method. but apparently it just print the object as it is.