# Overriding a function's toString() in node exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to override a toString() method, but getting into difficulties.
Already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805263/node-js-overriding-tostring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu), but still no luck.

My code is as follows:

```
var Foo = function(arg) {
    // some code here...

    return function (a, b, c) {
       // return function code...
    };
};

Foo.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "string representation of function";
};

exports.bar(arg) {
    return Foo(arg);
};
```

In another module:

```
var mod = require('the-module-from-above');
console.log(mod.bar().toString()); // prints return function source code.
```

My question is, how come my toString() function isn't called, and how can I make it get called?

thank you.

Comment: `Foo` is not a constructor in your code, and when `return`ing an object the prototype will be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set things on a function's prototype if you're using the function as a constructor with `new`. Since you don't appear to be doing that here, you need to set the `toString` function on the actual function you return.

```
function fooToString() {
    return "string representation of function";
}

var Foo = function(arg) {
    // some code here...

    var ret = function (a, b, c) {
       // return function code...
    };
    ret.toString = fooToString;
    return ret;
};
```

You could also add the `toString` function when you actually create the object in the `bar` function, if you'd prefer to do that.

```
exports.bar(arg) {
    var foo = Foo(arg);
    foo.toString = fooToString;
    return foo;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on it for hours.